# Least Common Ancestor algorithm variation

Tags: algorithm, tree

```
    root
    /   \
    A     B
  / | \  / \
  C D E F   G
 |         |
 H         I
```

Given a tree and a list of types {C,D,E,F}. The summary is {A,F} 
(as CDE implies A)

If the list of types was {C,D,E,F, I}. The summary is root (as cde implies a, i implies g, and gf implies b, and ab implies root).

At a high level, how would the algorithm for finding the summary work? (pseudo code only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo Code, a simple tree traversal

```
String getSummary(Node node){
  if(node contains element in the set)
    return node name;
  else
    String result = "";
    for(Node child : node.getChildren){
        if(child contains element in the set)
           result += getSummary(child);
    }
    if(result are all the name of its children)
       return node name;
    return result;
```

Comment: Would I be using the root node to get the summary for the entire tree using the given list of types?

Comment: @user3603183 Yes, you should use the root node

Comment: @user3603183 one thing to clarify is what happen if the list of types are {C,D,E,F,A, I}?

Comment: Should be the same as {CDEFI} = {root}. Would that change the logic in the pseudocode?

Comment: @user3603183 Sorry, I mean {C,D,A, I}

Comment: The summary of that would be {AI}  . as A implies C/D/E

Comment: @user3603183 ok, so we only need to check if the node's name contains one element in the set or not, and we can return the whole node from that point without checking further, I have change the first `if` of the pseudocode!